# MomentJS displaying current time instead of API stored time

Tags: momentjs

[enter image description here][1]I need assistance in momentjs.
I’m using momentjs for date and time formats.

The issue I’m facing is that momentjs is displaying the current date and time instead of  the correct date and time that is stored in the API.

Below is my code:(eventStartUTC) is the stored time in the API.

```
var startTime = moment(item.eventStartUTC).format("HH:mm" + " - ");
var endTime = moment(item.eventEndUTC).format("HH:mm");
var finalTime = startTime.concat(endTime);
```

Values for eventStartUTC and eventEndUTC as stored in the API: 
item.eventStartUTC - "26/11/2017 06:00:00", 
item.eventEndUTC - "28/11/2017 15:00:00"

date and time api values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ajO3.png

Comment: What is the value of `item.eventStartUTC` and `item.eventEndUTC`?

Answer (score 0):

As [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) states:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

Since input (`item.eventStartUTC` and `item.eventEndUTC`) is neither in ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a live sample:

```js
var item = {
  eventStartUTC: '26/11/2017 06:00:00',
  eventEndUTC: '28/11/2017 15:00:00'
};
var startTime = moment(item.eventStartUTC, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format("HH:mm" + " - ");
var endTime = moment(item.eventEndUTC, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format("HH:mm");
var finalTime = startTime.concat(endTime);
console.log(finalTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The above solutions works but then I'm pulling the date and time from an API instead of hard coding.

Comment: @ninja I've hardcoded values to make a working snippet, you simply have to use `moment(String, String)` as described in the first part of the answer. I think that data from you API has always the same format.

Comment: I did that and getting error: "Invalid date" . I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @ninja are you sure that `item.eventStartUTC` and `item.eventEndUTC` have the value you provided in your question?

Comment: Yes values are correct. I have attached the link to my post so that you can see the values I want to display.
This is what I implemented:

var startTime = moment(item.eventStartUTC, 'DD/MM/YYYY 
    HH:mm:ss').format("HH:mm" + " - ");
 var endTime = moment(item.eventEndUTC, 'DD/MM/YYYY 
   HH:mm:ss').format("HH:mm");
 var finalTime = startTime.concat(endTime);
  console.log(finalTime);